# как добавить npm команду в автозагрузку в ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, npm, cron

Есть .sh скрипт который запускает npm команду "npm start". Этот же скрипт нужно добавить в автозагрузку.

Я пробовал использовать встроеный планировщик в ubuntu, добавлял скрипт в 'rc.local' , добавлял в скрипт в crone. Во всех случаях без результатно.
Если просто запустить данный скрипт то он прекрасно работает, а в автозагрузке не запускается.

Так как  в Linux я новичок возможно есть какие то нюансы о которых я не знаю.

Задача состоит в том, чтоб запустить команду "npm start" после загрузки ubuntu. Данная команда запускает приложение с интерфейсом.

пример sh скрипта :

```
 #! /bin/bash

 cd "/home/User1/Рабочий стол/startScriptLinux"
 npm start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Папка для автозагрузки находится тут: `~/.config/autostart`. Вам нужно создать в ней .desktop файл примерно с таким содержимым:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=NPM Start
Comment=Start NPM
Exec=./script.sh
Path=~/path/to/script/
Terminal=false (или true)
```

Прежде чем добавлять его в автозагрузку, попробуйте запустить `xdg-open file.desktop`, чтобы проверить, нет ли ошибок (например в путях).

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую начать отладку с анализа переменных окружения. Когда работает Cron у переменной $PATH значение обычно отличается от значения в shell'е.

Создайте файл /home/User1/test.sh (с правами на выполнение) и напишите в нем примерно следующее:

```
#!/bin/bash
env > /home/User1/envdump_shell.txt
set > /home/User1/setdump_shell.txt
```

и выполните его из shell'а.

Затем поменяйте `_shell.txt` на `_cron.txt` в именах файлов, в которые происходит запись и повторите из cron'а (или из rc.local) - скорее всего окажется, что переменная path не соответствует или что то в этом роде. В идеале в скриптах, выполняемых не из пользовательского окружения нужно использовать абсолютные пути.

Вторая частая проблема - права доступа: например, если npm хочет писать в лог-файл, а у него нет прав - процесс с большой вероятностью не будет работать.